# Touchpad not working - Chuwi Lapbook Pro - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, touchpad, synaptics

I have a Chuwi Lapbook Pro and I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04. The touchpad does not work at all, not even detected in the settings. I've tried installing various Synaptics and libinput drivers and nothing is working. It seems like it's the libinput and Synaptics drivers conflicting with each other. If I completely uninstall libinput and install synaptics, then the trackpad works and is detected, but the keyboard doesn't. I tred reinstalling the system multiple times and occasionally it recognizes the touchpad in the "try Ubuntu" section, but stops detecting it after full installation. I even tried to install Lubuntu but it didn't work in there either. Where to start? I'm brand new to linux so I have no idea. A USB mouse works fine. I also tried installing Ubuntu 21.04. Still no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Might be relevant. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/512280/55205 Also check if touchpad works with rolling release distros (e.g. Manjaro), which would have a newer kernel with better compatibility.

Comment: I tried manjaro, It isn't recognized on there either.

Comment: Then ask in the Manjaro Forums as well.